# Scala dynamic import

Tags: scala, reflection, import

How can I dynamically import packages/classes in scala?

Example: can I have a code like this or similar?

```
object Test {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val pack = "java.util.List"
    import pack
   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html#instantiating-a-type-at-runtime

Comment: This question is already asked and answered there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920117/can-you-import-dynamically-in-scala, but have look to dynamic import https://scalac.io/dynamic-member-lookup-scala/